# Neon-animated-pages does not resize

Tags: jquery, polymer

I'm using Polymer 1.0 in my website. I'm trying to get a `<neon-animated-pages>` element to work in conjunction with my `<paper-tabs>`.

The issue I have is using this affects the layout structure of my web page. It works fine, but since the positioning of the pages (`<neon-animatable>`) element is implicitly absolute, the wrapping element `<neon-animated-pages>` does not expand to fit the content. The content for my pages varies in height, so my footer (content after this) overlaps this in the background.

You can visualize it as an image slider, with variable height images which is followed by some content.

Is there any work-around for achieving this? Or should I create my own element bound to the paper-tabs (If so, can you provide a general idea to achieve this)? I can remove the absolute position, but it ruins the animation flow on page change.

Here is somewhat that I have:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="scope">
<paper-tabs selected="{{tab}}">
  <paper-tab>TAB1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB2</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

<neon-animated-pages class="flex layout vertical" selected="{{tab}}" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
  <neon-animatable class="flex">
    <div class="someClass">Page 1</div>
  </neon-animatable>
  <neon-animatable class="flex">
    <div class="someClass">Page 2</div>
  </neon-animatable>
</neon-animated-pages>
</template>
<div class="some-content">Some more content</div>
```

Any advice?

Comment: I had the same problem. I searched a workaround with but no solution found. I think that element has been created for pages only. My solution is to  modify the neon-animated-pages element itself to adapt to content.

https://github.com/maxiplay/neon-animation

I will try a pull request.